# is an admin role needed to upload a test flight for a new app?

Tags: ios, testflight

We recently hired a freelancer to work on an app. We gave him the "App Manager" role but he's asking for the admin role to be able to upload a test flight?

The app manager role already showed the ability to upload test flights in the list of privileges for it.

He sent an image with the following errors:

No profiles for "com.xxx.test" were found. xcode couldn't find any ios app development provisioning profiles matching "com.***.test"

Cannot create a ios app development provisioning profile for "com.xxx.test". personal development teams, including "Dev Name", do not support the Apple Pay and Push notifications capabilities.

Comment: In App Store Connect, "Users and Access"—>"People"—>that person. In "Additional Resources," is "Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles." checked?

Comment: @lazarevzubov no it's not. should it be enabled? and if so would that introduce any security risk?

Comment: For any kind of distribution, a developer must have access to certificates. Without a certificate installed on their machine and a provisioning profile including the certificate, it's not possible to upload a build to Test Flight or use any other kind of distribution. Having this in place, I think the role "App Manager" is not necessary, "Developer" should be enough. The role might introduce a bigger risk, as an app manager can edit the app in App Store Connect and do other things that you probably don't want an outsource developer to do.